# gdalbuildvrt strips attribute table

Tags: gdal, vrt, gdalbuildvrt

I would like to create a virtual raster from an .img file that has associated .ige, .rde, .rrd, and .xml files. I am doing this to enable virtual I/O so I want an "exact copy" of the original raster.

I am just calling this from the command line:

`gdalbuildvrt file.vrt file.img`

This creates a VRT but the attribute table is stripped; instead of categorical data I now have continuous values. How can I fix this?

Comment: Open the .vrt file with text editor. Does it contain element GDALRasterAttributeTable https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html?

Comment: No it doesn't. It has a single `VRTRasterBand` with a `ColorTable` but not an attribute table

Comment: It seems that there is some RAT support in vrt https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/743 but RATs are rather uncommon. It might be better to ask directly from gdal-dev mailing list.

Comment: Do you get a different result if you use `gdal_translate -of VRT file.img file.vrt` instead of `gdalbuildvrt`?

Comment: No I tried `gdal_translate` as well and got the same result as with `gdalbuildvrt`.